# Java Checkbox Save

Tags: java, checkbox

I need some help with saving checkboxes, I'm new in this.

What I want to do is to save the Settings:

```
if(e.getSource() == einstellung){


        JFrame meinJFrame = new JFrame();
        meinJFrame.setTitle("JRadioButton Beispiel");
        meinJFrame.setSize(400,300);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
 //Checkbox 1

        JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox("Activate Wall at the score of 500k.", false);

        panel.add(check);

      //Checkbox 2
        JCheckBox check1 = new JCheckBox ("Activate Trump Tower at the score of 1 million.", false);

        panel.add(check1);           

        meinJFrame.add(panel);
        meinJFrame.setVisible(true);
```

It's for a little game I am creating and I just want to save the checkboxes, so they are checked (or not) when I start the program again.

Comment: You basically need to consider how to persist application's state (e.g. the checked checkboxes) across restarts. You could e.g. store which checkboxes are checked in a file or a in a [SQLite database](https://www.sqlite.org/) whenever any checkbox is changed, or when the application is closed. When it is opened, you need to read from this file/database again to set the checkboxes to their correct value.
Your whole code is not necessary for this question. Please in the future paste only the relevant snippets of your code here. Thanks!

Comment: Im new here and edited the post, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want the last settings configuration to be saved even after the user has exited the application. To do that, the easiest way is to maintain a **.properties** file inside your jar, which should be read on startup, load the settings and then edit and save the file whenever the user changes the settings. Even if that's not the case, you should create a class that holds these settings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yeah thats excactly what i want, i'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Properties` class.

It makes it easy to:

1. get/set individual properties
2. save/load all the problem to a file